# node js POST not getting data using React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am submitting a form and the following gets called...

```
handleLogin(){
    fetch('http://localhost:8080', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({
         username: this.state.username,
         password: this.state.password
        })
    });

}
```

It makes a POST request to my restAPI. The request works, but the data is not passed...

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.username);
    ....
```

This prints out undefined, meaning password and username are not passed through the call. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First thing you should do is check the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools. There, you can see what data is exactly sent in the request. I would also recommend printing `this.state` before calling `fetch()`.

Comment: @MouadDebbar I did print `this.state`, its all good. Ill check the network

Comment: @MouadDebbar so I check the network, and under header tab > Form Data, it tells me that the right credentials were passed. I'm very confused as to why I cannot retrieve it

Comment: Ok this means one thing. Node is not parsing your data as json. Could you print `req.body`? You will need to use `bodyParse.json()` as a middleware.

Comment: @so when I print `req.body` I get an empty array, `{}`, also on POST I get redirect to a page `cannot POST` but yet it still `console.log` everything inside my `app.post`

Comment: Are you using the `bodyParse.json()` middleware?

Comment: @MouadDebbar Im not sure if Im using it properly, I added `app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))`

Comment: I think `app.use(bodyParser.json())` should be enough in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express by default doesn't parse the body of the request. In order to enable parsing, you will need to use a middleware such as [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser). You can find some information in the [express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body).

Also, the client side needs to indicate that it's sending `json` data. That can be achieved with the `Content-Type` header. There is a pretty good tutorial about `fetch()` [here](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch). You can jump directly to the `Request Headers` section which is relevant for your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 7070;
    const BASEURL = process.env.BASEURL || 'http://localhost/7070';

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.listen(PORT, function() {   console.log('Server running on'+BASEURL);
     });
```